# Add new data to mongo DB, using certain conditions

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, chatbot

I am trying to create a chatbot which could take tag, patterns and responses from user and the add the values to database in MongoDB. I am new to MongoDB. I have created a database and a collections into that database.

[image]

As seen above I have the collection in this format. I have an intent array which includes tags, patterns and responses.

If a user is trying to add a new details with a tag, not present in our database it will add a new record inside the collections using the below command.

```
y = mycol.find_one_and_update({'_id':ObjectId('64eee4e7bc3e2d46e9c6723f')},
                         {'$push': new_data })
```

The above code is working fine, but my concern is if a user enters completely details with a tag that is present in our collections it shall be added to the patterns and responses inside that tag rather than creating a new object.

I tried with the below code:

```
for i in all_data['intents']:
    if i['tag'] == data_push['intents'].get('tag'):
        mycol.find_one_and_update({'_id':ObjectId('64ef12c4d32f43f543a156b1')},
                                  {'$push': {'patterns':data_push['intents'].get('patterns')}},
                                  {'$push': {'responses':data_push['intents'].get('responses')}})
```

Getting an Error:
OperationFailure: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField.", 'code': 16410, 'codeName': 'Location16410', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1693390163, 25), 'signature': {'hash': b'\xeb\x10\xe5\xd8\xb7\x03\x8d8a}\xbd\x02Y\x90:\xba\xbc\xd0\xb7K', 'keyId': 7265762819927179269}}, 'operationTime': Timestamp(1693390163, 18)}

Tried a new method of adding the values but not correct. Creating new objects.

```
for i in all_data['intents']:
    if i['tag'] == data_push['intents'].get('tag'):
        mycol.find_one_and_update({'_id':ObjectId('64ef14cb122d85d7b5059ad6'),
                                   'intents.tag':i['tag']},
                                  {'$push': {'intents':{'responses':data_push['intents'].get('responses')}}})
```